# rmagick: doing the polaroid effect, changing the pictures caption

Tags: ruby, rmagick

it's about rMagick and the polaroid effect.

```
image = image.polaroid do
  self.font = "Tahoma"
  self.caption = name
  #self[:caption] = name
  self.shadow_color = "gray40"
  self.pointsize = 12
end
```

This is how I tried to change it's caption, but both versions don't work.

Any ideas?

Yours Joern.

Answer (score 1):

okay `image[:caption] = name` before doing the polaroid effect is the solution